# Como recorrer un JSON que retorna GraphQl

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

estoy empezando a aprender javascript, y tengo un servidor con GraphQl, cuando realizo una consulta, me retorna un JSON, pero no he sabido como recorrerlo.

Esto es lo que me retorna

```
{
"data": {
   "getAllRequests": [
      {
         "id": 11
      },
      {
         "id": 0
      }
   ]
 }
}
```

Ahora bien puedo colocar directamente la ruta si quiero obtener algo, así

```
resData.data.getAllRequests[0].id
```

Pero aun no se como puedo conseguir por medio de un for que recorra todos los id, y me los muestre. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
for(var i in resData.data.getAllRequests){
            for(var j in resData.data.getAllRequests[i]){

            }
        }
```

Pero no me retorna exactamente el id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recorrer el objeto tienes varias opciones, sin embargo lo que realmente deseas es recorrer el `Array` que viene en el atributo `getAllRequests` de tu objeto `data`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea recorrer un `Array` que contiene elementos (objetos) JavaScript. El `Array` es el valor de un atributo en un objeto que se recibe desde [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dado que el objeto que recibes tiene una estructura conocida, podemos recorrer su estructura y extraer la información relevante usando un bucle `for`, ya que es lo más adecuado según el planteamiento del problema.

En el código que pones de ejemplo en tu pregunta, veo que usas un bucle [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in), sin embargo, de acuerdo a la documentación de dicho bucle, este se usa para recorrer objetos, y en tu caso tu deseas recorrer un `Array`.

Para lograrlo usaremos el bucle [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of).

```js
const obj = {
  "data": {
    "getAllRequests": [
      {
        "id": 11
      },
      {
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}

const arr = obj.data.getAllRequests; // <= éste atributo contiene un array

for(let element of arr) {
  console.log('id: ', element.id); // <= cada elemento del array es un objeto
}
```

A veces tendemos a confundir la terminología y por lo tanto es común este tipo de errores.

Como GraphQL nos devuelve un objeto, nos vemos tentados usar el bucle `for...in` para recorrer cualquier elemento de nuestro objeto. Sin embargo, en este caso, el atributo `gatAllRequests` contiene como valor un `Array`, cuyos elementos son objetos JavaScript.

Otra forma de recorrer un `Array` es el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), la diferencia está en que el método `forEach()` iterará sobre todos los elementos del array sin que podamos evitarlo (a menos que lancemos una excepción), en cambio el bucle `for...of` podemos detenerlo con la sentencia `break`. Otra diferencia está en el hecho que el método `forEach()` ejecuta una función callback por cada elemento del array.

El código usando el método `forEach()` podría quedar así:

```js
const obj = {
  "data": {
    "getAllRequests": [
      {
        "id": 11
      },
      {
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}

const arr = obj.data.getAllRequests; // <= éste atributo contiene un array

arr.forEach((element) => {
    console.log('id: ', element.id);
});
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D, definitivamente me ayudo, es mucho mas rápido que un for in

Comment: Me alegra que te haya podido ayudar.